# Last 3 Digit Swift Code Entered Wrong Branch Than It Should Be. What should i do?

Tags: international-transfer, swift, iban

I sent a payment through international bank transfers with the last digit of BIC/Swift Code different that it is supposed to. The IBAN and account holder name are correct. The last 3 digits of BIC/Swift Code should be XXX but I entered with number (the specific branch number of the bank).

I know the transfer is successful because the money didn't come back to the sender bank. But, they said they still haven't got any payment. Is there any difference transferring to different branch of bank (it's the same bank tho)? And can they check it to the branch I sent it to?

Comment: 'I know the transfer is successful because the money didn't come back to the sender bank.' This process may take many days before payment is returned. Request that your bank put a trace on the funds to see where they ended up.

Comment: Yesterday I wired money to my overseas bank account in Australia. I put the wrong branch in swift code (the last 3 digits) that is in a different state, I even put the incorrect branch address, they moved recently. But the BSB number and the account number are correct. I got my money today. Make sure to do your research to avoid any hesitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "But, they said they still haven't got any payment"

how long are you talking? And what destination country?

It's normal in some cases for banks to hold it for a few days.  (Say, 3 max.)

(They simply do this to make a few dollars interest on the float of all the money moving around, and simply lie and say there's a technical reason.)

The exact problem you describe ("NNN" rather than "XXX") generally is not a problem.

Comment: Germany, and counting from 17th July (yesterday in my Timezone right now) it’s 3 working days. Alright, then I’ll confirm it again with them. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Germany usually has only short delays - if you sent from (say) USA it is possible it won't arrive .. won't be given to the recievor .. for another day or two.  In the future try ofx.com or any competitor business!  it's cheaper.

Comment: did it ever show up, @samuelchristian ?!